# How Do You Use Debugger With Webpack

Tags: javascript, debugging, webpack, breakpoints, developer-tools

I am using React, Redux, ImmutableJs in a webpack build. The output bundle just seems to be a mystery so until now all the debugging I have done, has been through `console` statements.

As per the recommendation, I am using the following command in my webpack.config.js file:

```
devtool : 'eval-source-map'
```

My question is, can we use the `Developer Tools` debugger to debug the output file (bundle.js)?

Doing a search within the file, I couldn't locate any of the variables (or function names) I am using in my build. Further down, I can see the list of all the modules in my app. However, adding a breakpoint within the files makes no difference. Which makes sense, as its converted that code into the bundle.

My question is, how do we debug the code running within the browser?

Can we add breakpoints & get `live` values? You know, all the `normal` javascript debugging process.

UPDATE TO @bebraw COMMENT:

It works in Chrome. Thats wonderful news. 
In FF Dev Version, I get the debug indicator, however, within the debugger tab, there is no indication of where its paused. None of the `Step In` or `Step Over` commands take us to the line.[image]

[image]

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you try adding a `debugger;` statement somewhere and see what happens? You should be able to walk through code just fine.

Comment: @bebraw Thank you, it does work in Chrome.

Comment: Are you running your code through webpack-dev-server? I think you should be able to see entire code structure in "sources" if you scroll down and open its entries. I don't know Firefox that well. It probably goes a little differently.

Comment: @bebraw yes I am using dev-server.& yes you can see all the individual modules, however, none of them are actionable, i.e. you can add breakpoints, but the code doesnt break upon interaction with the page elements.

Comment: Ok, hard to say what's going on then. I've seen similar behavior with `constructor` but putting a breakpoint at `render()` and logic side worked for me.